# Reduce string and keep zeroes intact

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am working with cell values in a format of "XXXX-000-000-000".

- Everything before the first hyphen needs to be removed, which I can do.
- The rest of the string needs to be reduced to whole numbers, with the hyphens, and any extra zeroes removed.

I'm having trouble keeping the zeroes in the right places.

- AD12-002-020-34  Needs to look like this:  2-20-34
- CA1-002-101-001  Needs to look like this:  2-101-1
- AD12-002-020-10  Needs to look like this:  2-20-10

For example:

```
dim ir as range

ir = "AD12-002-020-100"

ir1 = InStr(ir, "-")
ir2 = InStrRev(ir, "-")
ir.Offset(0, 1) = Mid(ir, ir1 + 1, ir2 - ir1 + 3)
```

Which gives me: 002-020-100

Suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you tell me what should be the output in case we have strings like these `"AD12-000-020-100"` or `"AD12-000-000-100"` or `"AD12-000-000-000"` or `"AD12-000-020-000"` or `"AD12-123-000-000"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, this would work as an UDF (user defined function)

```
Function STRIP(r As String)
    If InStr(1, r, "-00", vbTextCompare) Then
        r = Replace(r, "-00", "-")
    End If
    If InStr(1, r, "-0", vbTextCompare) Then
        r = Replace(r, "-0", "-")
    End If
    Dim v As Variant, s As String, i As Long
    v = Split(r, "-")
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        s = s & "-" & v(i)
    Next i
    STRIP = Right(s, Len(s) - 1)
End Function
```

you would simply call that from any cell with `=STRIP(A1)` where `A1` is a reference to any cell you want to split

example:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    s = "AD12-002-020-34"
    s = Replace(s, "-0", "-")
    s = Replace(s, "-0", "-")
    ary = Split(s, "-")
    ary(0) = ""
    s = Mid(Join(ary, "-"), 2)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for good working solution and a similar approach to mine but yours is possibly better :)

Answer (score 3):

A UDF isn't necessary (but obviously a MUCH better idea!):

`=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))-1)*1&"-"&VALUE(MID(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))+1,FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))+1)-FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))-1))&"-"&VALUE(MID(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))+1)+1,LEN(A1)))`

Comment: I pretty much know nothing about formulas so just looking at yours gives me goose bumps :P did you just come up with it or used some sort of a generator?

Comment: An alternate formula solution: `=--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)&"-"&--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99*2,99)&"-"&--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99*3,99)`

Answer (score 3):

A [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) approach

```
Sub TestCleanNames()
   Debug.Print CleanString("AD12-002-020-34")
   Debug.Print CleanString("CA1-002-101-001")
   Debug.Print CleanString("AD12-002-020-10")
End Sub

Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
      'remove first portion
      .Pattern = "(.+?)-"
      CleanString = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
      .Global = True
      'trim leasfing zeroes
      .Pattern = "(\-|^)(0)+([1-9])"
      CleanString = .Replace(CleanString, "$1$3")
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Can I also play? :p

A One liner

`Debug.Print Mid(Replace(Replace(Replace(Mid(sString, InStr(1, sString, "-")), "-000", "-"), "-00", "-"), "-0", "-"), 2)`

Where `sString` is a valid `"XXXX-000-000-000"` string

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub x()    
    'Technically, you don't have to declare variables, but it prevents typos:
    Dim ir As String
    Dim ir1 As String
    Dim ir2 As String
    Dim ir3 As String
    ir = "AD12-002-020-100"

    'First, get rid of the first 5 characters:
    ir = Right(ir, Len(ir) - 5)

    'Isolate each section. Convert to Int to get rid of leading zeros:
    ir1 = CInt(Left(ir, 3))
    ir2 = CInt(Right(Left(ir, 7), 3))
    ir3 = CInt(Right(ir, 3))

    'Return the result:
    MsgBox ir1 & "-" & ir2 & "-" & ir3
End Sub
```

Comment: why upvote? your code **fails** for the second variant `CA1-002-101-001`

Comment: you probably haven't notices that the first part of the string varies in length so the reason for inaccurate result is `(Right(ir, Len(ir) - 5))` the 5

Comment: @mehow, Yup, you're right. And my attempts to fix this are ending up with it looking more and more like a minor variation of Gary's Student's code. I'll bow to the more succinct coder on this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd throw my hat in the ring on this one.  Note that all versions are assuming the cells to be converted are in column A starting in cell A1.

As a macro:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim arrResults() As String
    Dim varText As Variant
    Dim varPart As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        ReDim arrResults(1 To .Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
        For Each varText In .Value
            ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
            For Each varPart In Split(Mid(varText, InStr(varText, "-") + 1), "-")
                arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) & "-" & Val(varPart)
            Next varPart
            arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = Mid(arrResults(ResultIndex, 1), 2)
        Next varText
        .Value = arrResults
    End With

End Sub
```

As a UDF:

```
Function tgrUDF(sText As String) As String

    Dim varPart As Variant

    For Each varPart In Split(Mid(sText, InStr(sText, "-") + 1), "-")
        tgrUDF = tgrUDF & "-" & Val(varPart)
    Next varPart

    tgrUDF = Mid(tgrUDF, 2)

End Function
```

As a formula:

> =--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)&"-"&--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT("
>   ",99)),99*2,99)&"-"&--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99*3,99)